# Get different md5 value when to verify ssh public key

Tags: ssh, hashsum, fingerprint

The author wrote ssh public finngerprint in the webpage.
[fingerprint](https://www.bjornjohansen.com/about-me)

> If you want to send me an email, my fingerprint is:
>   5029 E0D0 F458 72E4 09D3 308D 1D51 378E E348 35B6

Now i make a verification.
For public RSA (SSH) key:

```
wget https://www.bjornjohansen.com/pubkey.txt  
ssh-keygen -l -E md5 -f  pubkey.txt
2048 MD5:f4:cd:6d:0f:0c:16:20:ea:f7:bc:c0:36:b9:29:16:c3bjornjohansen@Endor (RSA)
```

For OpenPGP (GnuPG) public key:

```
wget https://www.bjornjohansen.com/E34835B6.asc 
ssh-keygen -l -E md5 -f E34835B6.asc 
E34835B6.asc is not a public key file.
```

What i got  is totally different from  the author wrote in webpage.
I can't send a message via twitter.

[image]

Is my method wrong or the author paste an outdated md5 value in his webpage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding isn't correct. Checking the SSH public key is irrelevant. The email fingerprint is for the PGP Public key which would require you to use GnuPG (aka gpg) to validate the fingerprint.

```
wget https://www.bjornjohansen.com/E34835B6.asc
gpg --import E34835B6.asc
gpg --fingerprint 5029E0D0F45872E409D3308D1D51378EE34835B6
```

The fingerprint is from above and will pull up Bjorn's public key for you. I should also mention, Bjorn's PGP Public Key is also expired as of 2018.

Comment: gpg --list-packets   E34835B6.asc